# PHP preg_replace not matching multiple whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So,

I've got some legacy HTML I'm trying to use regex to remove the cruft from. Something like

```
<div class="al-list-head"><span>Another List</span></p>
<h3>Destinations</h3>
</div>
```

Another variant in HTML could be

```
<div class="al-list-head">
<p><span>Another List</span></p>
<h3>Lounge</h3>
</div>
```

(The CMS adds in redundant `<p>`'s sometimes).

My regex works for the most part (second sample) but not the first. I've tried a bunch of character classes, but can't seem to match the gap between the last `</h3>` and the final `</div>` in the the first sample.

My regex is...

```
$html = preg_replace( '/<div class=\"al-list-head\">[\s](<p>?)(<span>Another\ List<\/span>)(<\/p>?)[\s]<h3>([^<\/>]*)<\/h3>[\s]<\/div>/is', '<h3 class="al-head">$4</h3>', $html );
```

After the `<\h3>` I've tried `[\s]`, `([\s]?)`, `([\s\b\n\r]*)` and even `(.*)` with no luck.

Any pointers?

I'm using this [handy little tool](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) to iterate and test, hopefully someone finds it useful too.

Comment: Try adding the `m` modifier: your regex ends with `/is`, try `/ism`.

Comment: @dangvy what's your expected output?

Comment: your command works for me http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s*`

```
$html = preg_replace( '/<div class=\"al-list-head\">\s*(<p>?)(<span>Another\ List<\/span>)(<\/p>?)\s*<h3>([^<\/>]*)<\/h3>\s*<\/div>/is', '<h3 class="al-head">$4</h3>', $html );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex, it could works for both example,

```
/<div\s*class=\"al-list-head\">\s*(<p>)?(<span>Another\s*List<\/span>)(<\/p>)?\s*<h3>([^<\/>]*)<\/h3>\s<\/div>/img
```

Replacement string:

```
<h3 class="al-head">$4</h3>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/3)